# Autofeel light bar mod

Tags: automotive, switching, led-driver, lighting

I purchased an Autofeel 30 inch light bar that has 4 rows of LEDs.

I have seen this bar advertised under a number of different names, but as far as I know it's the only one with 4 rows of LEDs (they all look the same). I have added a picture of the bar, so you may recognize it from that.

[image: photo of light bar]

It's a cheap Chinese bar, but it works well for the purpose I want it for which is a side flood light.

My problem is it also has 4 modes (white steady, white strobing, yellow steady, yellow strobing). These modes are selected by a time delay, so if the unit is switched off and on in less then 7 seconds, it will select the next mode.

If switched off and on again after more then 7 seconds, it will go back to steady white.

I have it rigged up to sync with my high beam and it's proving to be a major pain in the rear (or front in this case).

My first thoughts (see my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/412148/delay-timer-for-car-bar-light-to-stop-mode-cycling)) were to build a time delay circuit that prevents the unit coming on in less then 7 seconds after it was switched off and I think I have that sorted. However one of the contributors mentioned it would be better to directly modify the light bar.

I have seen it advertised with an extra wire which you use to manually select the mode (that's what I thought I was buying) so I guess it's possible to modify the bar to make it work like that.

So my question is, which is a long shot, I know: Does anyone have any information, circuit, advice to modify the light bar so it only works on white steady?

I have written to the manufacturers and the supplies but got nothing back, except how to use it with the time delay to switch the mode.

Comment: FYI, questions here about modifying consumer products typically require that you provide a schematic (either from the manufacturer, or by your own reverse-engineering etc.). Without that, the question of how to modify it is unanswerable, as readers aren't being given (by you) the original circuit which needs modification. That's why this type of question, without a schematic, isn't a good fit for this site :-( Unlike a typical forum, Stack Exchange sites are Q & A - minimal chat (except in the chat rooms :-) ) - so the questions need to provide all relevant info needed to write an answer.

Comment: After more reading, I see that in the middle of this question, is the difference between this one and your [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/412148). *That* one was about adding an external delay circuit, and you state you've found a solution to do that. *This* one (although it repeats much of the background info, and hence looks similar to the first question) is about modifying the light bar instead, to do the same thing. So I'll withdraw my duplicate vote, but vote to close as off-topic, as it's similar to a repair question with no schematic, as explained above.

Comment: Find the supply point closest to the leds and feed that... if not use the timer circuits given to you in the answers to your other, similar, question...

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike I should have thought of that. If I identify that point and replace all the circuit before it with a led driver of sufficient wattage problem solved thank you

Comment: BTW that previous question was my original question which I found a solution for. I appreciate this question was asked without a schematic as the point of the question was to obtain a schematic or assistance with knowledge of how to proceed without a schematic.